# Fourier Transform based Image compression before text-detection

Tags: signals, jpeg, image-compression, dct, text-recognition

> DCT of 1x8 data **[8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64]** --(dct8)--> **[100,-52,0,-5,0,-2,0,0.4]**.
>   Now if we truncate (i.e. discard low-frequency components) and then take Inverse DCT of that 1x4 data over 1x8 interval as : **[100,-52,0,-5]** --(idct8)--> **[8,15,24,32,40,48,57,63]** . i.e. we almost get the same data.
>
> Can this be used to reduce size of jpeg images by applying 2D DCT,
>   followed by discarding low frequency values (because most of signal's
>   energy lies @high frequency)i.e. discarding the bottom-right quadrant, followed by 2D IDCT?

P.S. : I have to work on '*text recognition*' so a lossy compression won't affect my performance rather it could be much much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most compression scheme, JPEG uses a series of compression step. What you are describing is one of them that JPEG already uses.

Comment: I know JPEG does this kind processing but then again if I apply this same algorithm to any already compressed jpeg then there is a decrement in size, sometime upto 80%, again information will be lost, but I don't need those noisy pixels anyway for detecting text regions, so **will it work** ?

Comment: Doing it a second time will not improve compression.